# "Insufficient priveleges to complete the operation", inspite of granting all necessary permissions

Tags: c#, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied",
"message":
{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},
"requestId":"b205e5d0-f929-418e-9153-f1994e2c0893",
"date":"2020-02-15T06:53:57"}
}
```

I am able to retrieve the authentication token from the server and have granted all the permissions through the AAD but still I'm facing the same issue.
Would be great if someone could help me out.
I am using the Microsoft Graph API.

Below is the code that I am using

```
private const string clientID = "XXXX";
        private const string addInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
        private const string tenant = "XYZ";
        private const string resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
        private const string appKey = "appkey";
        static string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, addInstance, tenant);

        private static HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
        private static AuthenticationContext context = null;
        private static ClientCredential credential = null;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
            credential = new ClientCredential(clientID,appKey);

            Task<string> token = GetToken();
            token.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(token.Result);

            Task<string> users = GetUsers(token.Result);
            users.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine(users.Result);
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetUsers(string result)
        {
            string users = null;
            string queryString = "api-version=1.6";
            var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/ *The Microsoft 365 account assosciated with the tenant* /users?"+ queryString;
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result);
            var getResult = await httpclient.GetAsync(uri);
            if (getResult != null)
            {
                users = await getResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return users;
        }


        private static async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string token = null;
            result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, credential);
            token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your token request code and also which `graph API` you are trying to consume both will be helpful to resolve the issue.

Comment: I've added the code, hopefully it helps in analyzing the issue

Comment: Did you have either `User.ReadWrite.All` or `User.Read.All` permission? and make sure you have clicked on `Grant admin consent` additionally check your token on [https://jwt.io/](https://jwt.io/) to confirm it has required permission there.

Comment: Both the permissions are granted and the token has been verified on the link that you provided (Signature Verified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried following way and perfectly worked for me.

```
       //Token Request End Point
        string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
        var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

        //I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recommended
        tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
            ["client_id"] = "b603c7be-a956_Your_Client_Id_a45996-e6921e61f36955",
            ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0loj_Your_Client_Secret_okjh8wL/yujh45lojhgg=",
            ["resource"] = "https://graph.windows.net" 
        });

        dynamic json;
        AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

        json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);


        //New Block For Accessing Data from Microsoft Graph Rest API
        HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6"));

        //Passing Token For this Request
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);

        //Check The Response and extract response data
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        dynamic objGpraphUserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        return objGpraphUserList
```

***Class Used:***

```cs
 public class AccessTokenClass
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
```

I got the User List as expected. See the screen shot.

[image]

***Validate Your Token :***

Check your token on https://jwt.io/ which should have `User.ReadWrite.All` or `User.Read.All` **Application permission**

[image]

> **Note:** 
>   You should have following permission on `Azure Active Directory Graph`

[image]
For more information please refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#basic-operations-on-users--)

Hope this would help.